# Elementary os updates not working

Tags: updates

I dont get any updates anymore. The update windows is empty.
I have also tried "sudo dpkg --configure -a" that have fix update problem before,with no luck...
Please help..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There was some problem that messed up the update screen. Elementary released new updates that solved it. In particular, you need to install the latest packagekit package:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install packagekit`

Source: https://medium.com/elementaryos/important-update-released-501c9d9f28b

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve that problem but you can easily replace elementary's native "app centre" with some another app manangement software like **Synaptic package manager**. I am using it for a while and it is far better than the app centre. You could easily install it by running these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing. I use the Gnome Software Center.

"sudo apt-get install gnome-software"

I find this one useful due to its GUI

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue last week and I was able to fix it with

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It installed all the missing updates and now I'm able to install updates from app center again.